# tf.optimizers.Adam.minimize GradientTape issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am migrating some code from Tensorflow v1 to v2 and I have some issues on using tf.optimizers.Adam.minimize.

The below code reproduces the issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf

args = {'layers': {'j': [4, 6, 8], 'q': [8, 2, 1], 'k': 7, 'pooling_type': 'average', 'decimation': 4, 'pooling': 1024, 'learn_scales': False, 'learn_knots': False, 'learn_filters': True, 'hilbert': True}, 'gmm': {'gmm_type': 'natural', 'trainable': False}, 'gmm_init': {'n_components': 10, 'max_iter': 1000, 'covariance_type': 'full', 'warm_start': True}}

class temp:
    def __init__(self, x, j=None, q=None, k=None, pooling_type='average',
                 decimation=2, pooling=2, index=0, **filters_kw):
        # Filter bank properties
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
          tape.watch(x)
          x_conv = tf.random.uniform((12,64,4201), dtype=tf.float32)
          # and so on

        inverse = tape.gradient(x_conv, x, output_gradients=x_conv) # in full code does not return None
        inverse = tf.random.uniform((4,3,16800), dtype=tf.float32) # added this just to let inverse pass

        reconstruction_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(inverse - tf.stop_gradient(x))

data = tf.random.uniform((4,3,16800), dtype=tf.float32)

layers = [temp(data, index=0, **args['layers'])]

# originally how loss is defined (gmm returns a float value for loss):
# loss, cat = gmm(mu, cov, tau, sx_proj, **args['gmm'])
loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(1.123)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
sx_proj = tf.random.uniform((64,5), dtype=tf.float32)
tau = np.random.rand(10,)

minimizer = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[tau, sx_proj], tape=tf.GradientTape(persistent=True))
```

Initially, I did not add 'tape=tf.GradientTape(persistent=True)' inside 'minimizer' but I received the following error:

```
ValueError: `tape` is required when a `Tensor` loss is passed. Received: loss=1.1230000257492065, tape=None.
```

After adding a gradient tape, I now get the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-82d22d49e786> in <module>
     27 optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
     28 
---> 29 minimizer = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[tau, sx_proj], tape=tf.GradientTape(persistent=True))
     30 
     31 # SOS , tape=tf.GradientTape(persistent=True)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py in minimize(self, loss, var_list, tape)
    524           None
    525         """
--> 526         grads_and_vars = self.compute_gradients(loss, var_list, tape)
    527         self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    528 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py in compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list, tape)
    257                     var_list = var_list()
    258 
--> 259         grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)
    260         return list(zip(grads, var_list))
    261 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
   1050     """
   1051     if self._tape is None:
-> 1052       raise RuntimeError("A non-persistent GradientTape can only be used to "
   1053                          "compute one set of gradients (or jacobians)")
   1054     if self._recording:

RuntimeError: A non-persistent GradientTape can only be used to compute one set of gradients (or jacobians)
```

My guess is it might be because I have a GradientTape in my class already so I tried defining a new gradient tape just for the minimization but that did not seem to work as well. Any suggestions?

For references, the original TF V1 code is in https://github.com/leonard-seydoux/scatnet/blob/master/example/main.py and the part that defines the minimizer is in line 107.

I will also leave the original gmm function below in case it's needed:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfd = tfp.distributions

MVNFC = tfd.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance

def gmm(mu, cov, tau, sx_proj, n_clusters=None, gmm_type='natural',
        trainable=True, cov_diag=None):
    """Gaussian mixture clustering."""
    if trainable is True:
        log_tau = tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(tau))
        eps = tf.eye(2)
        d = cov_diag
        gm = [MVNFC(mu[c], tf.nn.elu(d[c]) * np.eye(2) +
                    tf.matmul(cov[c], tf.transpose(cov[c])) + eps)
              for c in range(n_clusters)]
    log_p = [gm[c].log_prob(sx_proj) for c in range(n_clusters)]
    cat = tf.stack([log_tau[c] + log_p[c] for c in range(n_clusters)], 1)

    # Choose your loss
    if gmm_type == 'natural':
        q = tf.math.reduce_logsumexp(cat, axis=1)
        loss = - tf.reduce_mean(q)

    return loss, cat
```

Comment: you have a very confusing code... the tape you have to pass to the minimize call is the one in the constructor of your class (where you do the forward pass and the loss calculation), but at this point calculate the gradient manually and use the optimizer to apply them

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia sorry about that, will it be easier if I provide a link to my colab or something? It's just that the actual code is quite long. Just to clarify, when you say calculate the gradient manually and use the optimizer to apply them, do you mean processing the gradients and then use ```apply_gradients()```?

Comment: there are many examples here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch on how to do that